# How to connect bootstrap year calendar with mysql base

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, calendar

I got problem with connecting bootstrap year calendar from bootstrap-year-calendar.com with my mysql base.

I make getEvents.php file, which is connecting with base and taking data of events. When I printing result from this file then all is ok and i see my events, but when I trying to include this result to DataSource in calendar script then I dont see any events.

Someone could send some examples how to do it?

My codes:

getEvents.php

```
<?php 

        require "bdd.php";
        $result = $bdd->prepare("SELECT `id`, `title`, `start`, `end`, `color`, `dsc`, `zlec`, `stanowisko` FROM `events`");
        $result->execute();
        $event_array = array();
        $result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($record = $result->fetch()) {
            $event_array[] = array(
                'id' => $record['event_id'],
                'title' => $record['event_name'],
                'start' => $record['start_event'],
                'end' => $record['end_event'],
            );
        }
    echo json_encode($event_array);

?>
```

calendar script I change to

```
dataSource: ['getEvents.php']
```

### ACTUALIZATION

@JeffHuijsmans Im not sure how to fix it.

Please tell me how to fetch into dataSource function result from my getEvents.php file ?

echo from getEvents file return

```
[{"event_id":"1","event_title":"XXX","event_start":"2017-10-04","event_end":"2017-10-06"}]
```

Default data in dataSource is looking like this:

```
dataSource: [
            {
                id: 0,
                name: 'Google I/O',
                location: 'San Francisco, CA',
                startDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 28),
                endDate: new Date(currentYear, 4, 29)
            }]
```

Comment: *"Someone could send some examples how to do it?"* - There are ample tutorials out there as well as official manuals to get started with. Try something then edit your post to contain what you tried. We'll be glad to take a look at it.

Comment: What is that spammy looking link in your comment @Bhargav?

Comment: Could you show me where is ANY tutorial about connecting bootstrap-year-calendar with mysql base? Becouse you are wrong.

Comment: *"Becouse you are wrong."* - Errr... huh?

Comment: I question the upvote.

Comment: @Bhargav please either remove your link or explain what it is (it doesn't even load, by the way). If you don't, I will report you.

Comment: Someone could help me ?

Comment: @AK994 `dataSource` should be an array of values. You're giving it the text string `getEvents.php`, NOT what that file returns.

Comment: @JeffHuijsmans thanks! I think you have right. I will try it soon

Comment: @AK994 no problem! Don't be afraid to ask here again if it still doesn't work :)

Comment: It doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "workaround" is iterate the data array and generate a string with data in calendar format.

Here works fine, hope helps.

Sample:

```
private function convertYearData(array $yearData) : string
    {
        if (empty($yearData)) {
            return 'null';
        }
        $data = '';
        foreach ($yearData as $event) {
            if (empty($data)) {
                $data =  "[{id:{$event['id']}, name:'{$event['name']}', type:'{$event['type']}', startDate: new Date('{$event['startDate']}'), endDate: new Date('{$event['endDate']}')}";
            } else {
                $data .=  ", {id:{$event['id']}, name:'{$event['name']}', type:'{$event['type']}', startDate: new Date('{$event['startDate']}'), endDate: new Date('{$event['endDate']}')}";
            }   
        }
        $data .= ']';
        return $data;
    }

    $yearDataArr = [
        [
            'id' => '1',
            'name' => 'Pesquisa Teste',
            'type' => 'Pesquisa',
            'color' => '#4da539',
            'startDate' => '2017-04-28 02:00:00',
            'endDate' => '2017-04-30 12:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'Media Teste',
            'type' => 'Media',
            'color' => '#00afe8',
            'startDate' => '2017-04-25 02:00:00',
            'endDate' => '2017-05-12 12:00:00',
        ],
        [
            'id' => '3',
            'name' => 'Email Marketing Teste',
            'type' => 'Email Marketing',
            'color' => '#af2828',
            'startDate' => '2017-03-25 02:00:00',
            'endDate' => '2017-05-17 12:00:00',
        ],
    ];
    $yearData = $this->convertYearData($yearDataArr);
```

after, in your html just echo your var $yearDate:

```
$('#calendar').calendar({ 
    language:'pt',
    enableContextMenu: false,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    selectRange: function(e) {
        editEvent({ startDate: e.startDate, endDate: e.endDate });
    },
    mouseOnDay: function(e) {
        if(e.events.length > 0) {
            var content = '';

            for(var i in e.events) {
                content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">'
                            + '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].type + '</div>'
                            + '<div class="event-type">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>'
                        + '</div>';
            }

            $(e.element).popover({ 
                trigger: 'manual',
                container: 'body',
                html:true,
                content: content
            });

            $(e.element).popover('show');
        }
    },
    mouseOutDay: function(e) {
        if(e.events.length > 0) {
            $(e.element).popover('hide');
        }
    },
    dayContextMenu: function(e) {
        $(e.element).popover('hide');
    },
    dataSource: <?php echo $this->yearData; ?>
});
```

Comment: It should work - I don't test it yet, but it looks fine. My dilemma is how it will work with editing/deleting events in my calendar. Thanks @LeoSarli

Comment: @AK999 I evolve my code a little bit. Now i aways load the data via Ajax, this way, all i need to do is update my database and re-populate the calendar data with setDataSource(data) method.

Comment: Sounds great! I will check it soon.

Comment: I got error about convertYearData function - it could be use only in Mozilla. Any ideas?